# Parse.com Friendlist Searching Json object

Tags: android, json, facebook, parse-platform

I'm stuck on a little problem for my Android app, and can't wrap my head around it

I'm currently using parse.com to store facebook profile information under the User table. The column name is profile and it's type is Object which is just a Json object. I'd like to be able to search the column for users with a specific name.

This is the constructor for my adapter...
public FriendListAdapter(Context context, final String searchCriteria){

```
    super(context, new QueryFactory<ParseUser>() {
        public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereContains("profile", searchCriteria);
            return query;
        }
    });
}
```

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `query.whereEqualTo()` method, and `findInBackground()`

Here are sample codes:

```
ParseQuery< ParseUser > query = new ParseQuery< ParseUser >();
        query.whereEqualTo("profile", searchCriteria);        
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback< ParseUser >() {
            @Override
            public void done(List< ParseUser > messages, ParseException e) {
                // Success!!
```